# How to get rid of margin in bootstrap css navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a responsive navigation bar in bootstrap and trying to customize it to my need to make my own design.

I managed to get the drop down on mobile size window but there is margin which i can't seem to get rid of on the right nevertheless i tried overriding the classes attributes (please check the image below) [image]

**I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and jquery-3.3.1**

```css
.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  color: #2a4068;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-default {
  color: #2a4068;
  background: #d8dfea;
  border-bottom: solid 0px #2a4068;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #2a4068;
}

.container {
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.navbar-header {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

.navbar-right {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.logoImage {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -7px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #2a4068;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover {
  background-color: #99b1d7;
  color: #2a4068;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#nav_links {
  display: block;
  color: #2a4068;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#navbar_menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 <title>Bootstrap</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand logoImage" href="index.php">
        <img src="images/logo_large.png" title="Asserter" alt="logo" width="110" height="35" class="large-logo" id="brand-image" />
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="navbar_menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class=""><a href="" class="" id="nav_links">Front</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="" class="" id="nav_links">Admin</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="" class="" id="nav_links">Profile</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="" class="" target="_blank" id="nav_links">Chat</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="nav_links">Notifications</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="" id="nav_links">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="nav_links">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="nav_links">Instagram</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a href="" class="" id="nav_links">Settings</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="" class="" id="nav_links">Log out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1-dev.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i need to have a perfect dropdown which lines up with the screen limits

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a working example here. So we can debug

Comment: You can use the snippet to provide your working example , i just turn your code into one and linked bootstrap to it

Comment: there is no margin in the snippet you shared @G-Cyr

Comment: @MohamedBenkedadra The code was provided by the op (i only turned it into a working snippet), we are still expecting a working example showing the issue described ;)

Comment: Perhaps, he is using bootstrap <4

Comment: @G-Cyr i don't know what you mean, how to do that ?

Comment: I'll share a working example. There I did not find any margin.

Comment: you just need to edit the snippet and update it with the missing code :)

Comment: @G-Cyr ok i edited the snippet exactly how i have it in notepad++ with same css except the picture of the logo is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found small paddings in the `.container-fluid` class. Rest I do not see any margins.

```css
 .navbar {height: 50px; color: #2a4068; margin-bottom: 0px;}

.navbar-default {color: #2a4068; background: #d8dfea; border-bottom: solid 0px #2a4068;box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #2a4068;}

.container {height: 50px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;}

.navbar-header {height: 50px;margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;}

.navbar-collapse {padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;}

.navbar-nav {margin-right: 0px;margin-left: 0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;margin: 0px 0px;}

.navbar-right {padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;margin-right: 0px;}

.logoImage {z-index: 1; margin-top: -7px;margin-bottom: 20px;}

.navbar-nav li {text-align: center;border-radius: 4px;color: #2a4068;cursor: pointer;}
.navbar-nav li:hover{background-color: #99b1d7;color: #2a4068;opacity: 0.7;}
#nav_links {display: block;color: #2a4068;font-weight: bold;}

#navbar_menu {width: 100%;margin-right: 0;margin-top: -10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand logoImage" href="index.php">
            <img src="images/logo_large.png" title="Asserter" alt="logo" width="110" height="35" class="large-logo" id="brand-image"/>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="navbar_menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class=""><a href="" class="" id="nav_links">Front</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="" class="" id="nav_links">Admin</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="" class="" id="nav_links">Profile</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="" class="" target="_blank" id="nav_links">Chat</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="nav_links">Notifications</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="" id="nav_links">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" id="nav_links">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" id="nav_links">Instagram</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="" class="" id="nav_links">Settings</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="" class="" id="nav_links">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This setup works well on chrome and firefox:

[image: This image shows a screenshot]

Ok, for the versions you are using adding this CSS will fix side margins. Although, I would recommend you to use it judicially.

```
.container-fluid > .navbar-header, .container > .navbar-collapse, .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

As for the top space, it's tough to see which property is causing that, chrome debugger is not able to select that element. It might be because of incorrect code or properties like box-shadow.

Update: Found the space bug below navbar. You actually have to specify the correct height for navbar header. For me this worked:

```
.navbar-header {
    height: 63px;
}
```

Comment: i edited the .container-fluid with 0 for paddings but still i have the same layout with the little padding or margin like the picture i provided and the margin from above too

Comment: Give your bootstrap, jquery versions. I'll debug. Also, you are testing on firefox right?

Comment: bootstrap 3.3.7 and jquery-3.3.1-dev.js and yes i am using firefox

Comment: Ok, I see it with these versions. Will be back with an update.

Comment: well i tried it again and deleted the cache but nothing! still getting the same bad result :/

Comment: btw your image still shows there is a margin between the header and the drop down list which i don't want to have, i want 0 margin between the header and the drop down list

Comment: I fixed the side margins. Working on top margin. Will update this answer soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186621/discussion-between-firasprogrammer-and-aditya-gupta).

Comment: ok the margin worked for me now, but for the margin from top, i added for the header a shadow which i need it for the design so i can't get rid of it or the design won't be as good as with it, so what can be done in this case ?